# Issue connecting to Database - JSP / Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, netbeans

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I've written similar projects that worked just fine but for whatever reason, the data is not being written to the database.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve at the moment is to grab the information from the sign up form and store it in my phpmyadmin db.

This code is identical (word for word) to another person doing this project and theirs is working fine. Leads me to believe the issue is with the JDBC driver or the the database in some way.

Here is the form page code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Phone Auction Site</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="login.jsp">
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In">
        </form>             

        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <form action="signup.jsp">
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            First Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
            Address:<br>
            <input type="text" name="address"><br>
            Phone Number:<br>
            <input type="text" name="phoneNum"><br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the signup.jsp page that gets the attributes, creates the instance and calls the saveToDatabase method

```html
<%@page import="phoneauctionronan.Customer"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Sign Up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            String address = request.getParameter("address");
            String phoneNum = request.getParameter("phoneNum");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");

            Customer c = new Customer(username, password, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNum, email);
            c.saveToDatabase();
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Customer class

```
package phoneauctionronan;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Customer 
{
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNum;
    private String email;

    public Customer()
    {

    }

    public Customer(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phoneNum, String email)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean saveToDatabase() 
    {
        boolean saved = false;
        Connection c = DBHelperClass.getConnection();
        if (c != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                Statement s = c.createStatement();
                String template = "INSERT INTO customer (username, password, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement inserter = c.prepareStatement(template);
                inserter.setString(1, this.username);
                inserter.setString(2, this.password);
                inserter.setString(3, this.firstName);
                inserter.setString(4, this.lastName);
                inserter.setString(5, this.address);
                inserter.setString(6, this.phoneNum);
                inserter.setString(7, this.email);
                inserter.executeUpdate();
                saved = true;
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return saved;
    }

     public Customer validateCustomer(String username, String password)
    {  
        boolean found = false;
        Connection c = DBHelperClass.getConnection();
        if(c!=null)
        {
            try 
            {
                Statement s = c.createStatement();

                String template = "SELECT * from customers where username = ? and password = ?";
                PreparedStatement inserter = c.prepareStatement(template);
                inserter.setString(1, username);
                inserter.setString(2, password);
                ResultSet resultSet = inserter.executeQuery();
                while(resultSet.next())
                {
                    this.id = resultSet.getInt("userID");
                    this.username = resultSet.getString("userName");
                    this.password = resultSet.getString("password");
                    this.firstName = resultSet.getString("firstName");
                    this.lastName = resultSet.getString("lastName");
                    this.address = resultSet.getString("address");
                    this.phoneNum = resultSet.getString("phoneNum");
                    this.email = resultSet.getString("email");
                    found = true;
                }
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
        }
        return this;
    }

    public String getUsername() 
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) 
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() 
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) 
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() 
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() 
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) 
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() 
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) 
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNum() 
    {
        return phoneNum;
    }

    public void setPhoneNum(String phoneNum) 
    {
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }

    public String getEmail() 
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) 
    {
        this.email = email;
    } 

    public int getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Finally here is the DBConnection class

```
package phoneauctionronan;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DBHelperClass 
{
    public static Connection getConnection() 
    {
        String host = "localhost";
        String dbName = "phones";
        int port = 3306;

        String mySqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port
                + "/" + dbName;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFound  !!!!" + e);
        }

        Properties userInfo = new Properties();
        userInfo.put("user", "root");
        userInfo.put("password", "password");
        try 
        {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mySqlUrl, userInfo);

            return connection;
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DBHelperClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Here is a pic of my customer table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jAeQ.png)

[Here a pic of the name of the db and table just in case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxMgU.png)

Completely lost as to what might be causing this!

Comment: Did some testing and c.saveToDatabase is returning false for some reason.

Comment: Have you checked if your code is throwing exceptions?

Comment: Apologies Mark. I have checked, no exceptions.

Comment: The only way `saveToDatabase` can return `false` if either `DbHelperClass.getConnection` returned `null` (which only happens if it an exception was thrown + caught), or if an exception was thrown + caught in `saveToDatabase`. So I think an exception was thrown, and you just need to find out what that exception was.

Comment: Thanks. I am far from experienced so excuse any silly issues with what I'm saying. I'm guessing exceptions would be thrown in the output window?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f76ac5d20ed519fd7e2208d093edab9c

Comment: You are logging them, I don't know which logging framework you use or how your config directs it, but I suggest you look at the Glassfish Server tab in Netbeans (and please: post the exception stacktrace in your question as text, not as an image).

Comment: Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn[/0.0.0.0:8080]
Warning:   The web application [/phoneauctionronan] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

Comment: Nope, that is not your problem, that is only a warning that you loaded a JDBC driver inside your application but didn't unregister it.

Comment: Try replacing the logging calls with a simple `exception.printStackTrace()` call.

Comment: Issue seems to have fixed itself overnight... lol